# Android onClick function for an edittext, How do I call the edittext?

Tags: android, onclick, android-edittext

I have an edittext form that can get filled, I want to clear it upon an onClick of a text, so I put an onClick that goes to my clear function in main.

I however, dont know how to properly target the edittext that I want. I want to clear TWO of them.

```
public void clear(View v) {
    @+id/toptext.setText("");

}
```

This is the XML for that specific text.

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/toptext"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#303030"
android:text="@string/toptext"
android:textAppearance="?
android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
android:textColor="#33B5E5"
android:textSize="50sp"
android:onClick="clear"  />
```

Comment: I want to clear TWO of them. ,, where is 2nd one

Comment: I figured if I can understand how to clear one, I can just clear the second right under it in the clear function.

Comment: Have any of the answers helped you?

Comment: Im working on using your answer mike. Give me a moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create instances of your EditTexts, using the `id` of the EditTexts in your xml layout. Then use `setText` on them and make them blank.

```
public void clear(View v) {

    EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.theIdOfYourEditText);
    EditText et2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.theIdOfYourOtherEditText);
    et.setText("");
    et2.setText("");
}
```

---

**Edit** for some reason the method above didn't work. This was the end solution:

```
// Put one of these in your onCreate method:

TextView tt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.toptext);
tt.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() { 
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.theIdOfYourEditText);
        EditText et2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.theIdOfYourOtherEditText);
        et.setText("");
        et2.setText("");

        return true;
    }
});

// or

TextView tt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.toptext);
tt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.theIdOfYourEditText);
        EditText et2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.theIdOfYourOtherEditText);
        et.setText("");
        et2.setText("");
    }
});
```

Comment: So I replaced your code with the IDs, and it compiles, but clicking on the textview doesnt clear the fields.

Comment: @user3204660 I tested it using your TextView and it doesn't work either. Must be something with the onClick method for the TextView. Try this and tell me if it works (using onClick and onTouch listeners): http://pastie.org/8643465

Comment: Did you try adding `android:clickable="true"` when trying to use the `onClick()`?

Comment: @codeMagic I used two TextViews in my test, and my other one worked, but the one he's using (that I copy and pasted) didn't.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.toptext);
tv.setText("Whatever you want!");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code:

```
public void clear(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.toptext) {
        ((EditText) v).setText(null);
    }
}
```

Similarly, add another if condition for another EditText.

Answer (score 0):

First, get reference to your TextView by calling findViewById:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.toptext);
```

Then use it to clear:

```
textView.setText("");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of setting "", u should use null as.

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.toptext);
textView.setText(null);
```

Comment: this is not true, ( "" ) is worked, problem is somewhere else,

Comment: if we use null instead of "" , we can see hint as well of EditText

Comment: you try to set TextView to null not EditText,and if you set to clear ("") you can see Hint in EditText

Comment: @Shayanpourvatan in que he is asking for editext and in xml comes to Textview. so i have used null, not getting you here "if you set to clear yoy can see Hint"??

Comment: i want to say if you set value in `EditTExt` to `""` you can see `hint`,don't needed to set null,

Answer (score 0):

Use the `param` passed to the `onClick()` (`v`)

```
public void clear(View v) 
{
    ((TextView)v).setText("");
}
```

Assuming you want to clear the text in the `TextView` that you have your `onClick` attached to. The `View` passed into `clear()` is the `View` that was clicked so you just cast it to the appropriate `View` (`TextView`) then you can use it as normal.

So this will clear the text on whichever `TextView` was clicked.